# How can I prove $ \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} i^2=\frac{n(n-1)(2n-1)}{6} $?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

> Suppose I know that
>   $$\sum_{i=1}^n i^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}\,\,\,\, \tag{1} $$
>   How can I prove the the following?
>   $$
> \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} i^2=\frac{n(n-1)(2n-1)}{6}
> $$

---

I have looked up the solution to the other problem but it seems to be a bit confusing to me. Is it possible to find a solution derived from equation 1 if you did **NOT** know this part:
$$
\frac{n(n-1)(2n-1)}{6}
$$

Comment: So are you asking how the first equation was derived?

Comment: using the first equation ,how can i derive the second one?

Comment: The only answer already answers that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply note that

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} i^2=\frac{n(n-1)(2n-1)}{6}=\left(\sum_{i=1}^n i^2\right)-n^2$$

indeed

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} i^2=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} i^2=\left(\sum_{i=1}^n i^2\right)-n^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}-n^2=\frac{n(n-1)(2n-1)}{6}$$

Comment: yes of course! just a typo, Thanks!

Comment: no, the formula comes from a DSP book(schaums' outline series)

Comment: @DontAskTheEye I mean that you can easily obtain and prove  the LHS by subtracting n^2 from the first one.

Comment: i edited my post to fit better what i am asking

Comment: @gimusi are you sure for the second Sum's starting value(under 'indeed')? it says i=0(the first one) and after the '=' it says  i=1(the second one).Maybe it needs some edit? If you leave it as is , it is missing one term.

Comment: @DontAskTheEye for i=0 you have 0 in the sum thus they are equal

Comment: i see it, i agree

Answer (score 1):

Put $n=N-1$ in $(1)$:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{N-1}i^2=\frac {\overbrace{(N-1)}^n\ \overbrace{N}^{n+1}\ [\overbrace{2(N-1)+1}^{2n+1}]}6=\frac {N(N-1)(2N-1)}6\tag{2}$$
Now write $n$ instead of $N$ in $(2)$ above:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}i^2=\frac {n(n-1)(2n-1)}6$$
Adding $0^2$ gives 
$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}i^2=\frac {n(n-1)(2n-1)}6$$

Answer (score 0):

The OP asked for how to get the RHS if you didn't know about it. One way to do this is through rising factorials, which work like ordinary integration.

define $$n^{\bar 1} = n$$
$$n^{\bar 2} = n(n+1)$$ and so on

We can rewrite $n^2 = n^{\bar 2} - n^{\bar 1}$

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n} i^2= \sum_{i=0}^{n} i^{\bar 2} - i^{\bar 1} = \frac{n^{\bar 3}}{3} - \frac{n^{\bar 2}}{2} + C$$

We can show $C = 0$ for $n = 0$

$$LHS = \frac{(n)(n+1)(n+2)}{3} - \frac{(n)(n+1)}{2} = \frac{(n)(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$$